# Nutch urlflter regex

Tags: regex, solr, nutch

I seem to be too stupid to get the regex exclusion right. I want to filter URLs of the domain: http://0.gravatar.com/. My regex-urlfilter.txt contains the following:

-http://0.gravatar.com(.*)
-^http://0.gravatar.com.[a-zA-Z0-9.\S]+$

but the URL is still being processed which leads to the error:

```
java.lang.Exception: org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException: Error from server at http://localhost:8983/solr/cdp: Server error writing document id http://0.gravatar.com/.. to the index
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.runTasks(LocalJobRunner.java:491)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:558)
Caused by: org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException: Error from server at http://localhost:8983/solr/cdp: Server error writing document id http://0.gravatar.com/.. to the index
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.executeMethod(HttpSolrClient.java:643)
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.request(HttpSolrClient.java:255)
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.request(HttpSolrClient.java:244)
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient.request(SolrClient.java:1219)
at org.apache.nutch.indexwriter.solr.SolrIndexWriter.push(SolrIndexWriter.java:247)
at org.apache.nutch.indexwriter.solr.SolrIndexWriter.commit(SolrIndexWriter.java:214)
at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexWriters.commit(IndexWriters.java:264)
at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexerOutputFormat$1.close(IndexerOutputFormat.java:54)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask$NewTrackingRecordWriter.close(ReduceTask.java:550)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:629)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:389)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$ReduceTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:346)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

So alternatively: Can I modify the code so the error is caught and the parsed URL content simply skipped. Or is there a setting to just skip instead of fail?

**UPDATE:** Thank you for the reply but it did not change the behaviour of the crawler. I have put `-^https?://0\.gravatar\.com and -^https?://1\.gravatar\.com` at the top of regex-urlfilter.txt. But URLs with 0.gravatar.com and 1.gravatar.com are still being fetched, parsed and indexed. And this still leads to the same error message above. Could it be, that those URLs are already injected and not being checked again by the url-filter?

I have found this description of the problem: https://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/regex-urlfilter-test-shows-negative-but-URL-still-crawled-td4081480.html and I find the answer regarding wasted CPU sensible. So I would much rather prefer to just skip the document when the indexing error occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out. It was a whole string of errors but the root cause was a lack of Heap Space for Solr. Starting Solr with `solr.cmd start -m 4g` solved the issue. I would never guessed that, as I am weeks deep in a crawl with millions of pages indexed. But it seems like the indexing failed not at a certain URL but at a certain stage in the indexing process. The whole URL quest was just a precursor. Once I had understood, injected URLs are not tested again and I needed to remove the -noFilter flag (see link in my Update), it became clear that the error propagated through URLs and the error needed to be elsewhere. Which, again, was very surprising given the stage of my crawl.

Answer (score 0):

This rule should exclude all URLs from `0.gravatar.com`.

```
-^https?://0\.gravatar\.com
```

There is no need to match the entire URL by a given regex. Every line must contain a single rule. Note that there are other URL filters (prefix, domain) which are simpler to use for this kind of exclusions.